# System frozing using Android Studio

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, adb

The problem is next: Ubuntu 14.04 lts just freezes forever, when i'm opening android monitor in Android Studio 2. I've done everything written here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/520013/ubuntu-14-04-freezes-when-running-project-in-netbeans-8-with-jdk-7
But it does not help=(.
In fact, the problem is in Adb, i just can't even take a look on the devices list, connected to laptop, using terminal, because the system becomes frozen too.
Help, please

Comment: Is there any error displayed or just freezes?

Comment: nothing. Just freezes

Comment: when i'm using command: "adb devices" in the terminal, it shows line: daemon not running. starting the new port ... And freezes